# How to link two different dashboards in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I Have 2 different dashboards and I am trying to link both the dashboards through links such that both the dashboards are accessible throught one other. I cannot put both in same page as load time will be more. The approach i have taken is by using drilldown

```
<drilldown>
  <link target=_blank> link to another dashboard </link>
</dashboard>
```

But this doesnot work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drilldown into another dashboard, it will look like this

```
<drilldown target="My New Window">
   <link>
      /app/dashboard_examples/form_table2
       form.sourcetype=$row.sourcetype$
    </link>
```

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.2/Viz/Dynamicdrilldownindashboardsandforms